# Will `os.walk` raise a StopIteration exception on the very first iteration if the path input is an empty directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Will `os.walk` raise a `StopIteration` exception on the very first iteration if the path input is an empty directory?

```
try:
    cur = "some path to an empty folder"
    directories = next(os.walk(cur))[1]
except StopIteration:
    msg = ''.join([str(x) for x in [
             "Error: ", repr(cur)
         ]])
    raise ValueError(msg)
```

Comment: You could try this by creating an empty directory, no?

Comment: Hmm, isn't the time spent posting this question several times longer than how it would take to actually test it? :)

Answer (score 0):

No, `os.walk` will **NOT** immediately raise a `StopIteration` exception if the path input is an empty directory. The following code does not raise an exception:

```
import os
import pathlib    
path = pathlib.Path(os.getcwd()) / "I_am_a_directory"
os.mkdir(path)
next(os.walk(path))
```